# Blocked History not working after Marshmallow upgrade in Lenovo K3 note

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lenovo, call-history

I recently upgraded my Android system in 'Lenovo K3 Note' to Marshmallow.
Now, I can't see Blocked History in the Contacts.
I could see the notification that some calls are blocked, but I can't see the Block History page.
Whenever I try to access this page, it redirects to the previous page.
Could you please help me fix this issue?

Any leads would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was able  to resolve this issue.

I followed these two links and now I can see the blocked history without having to lose the Call logs, blocked list etc :

- [Lenovo K3 Note: Blocked History not opening after Android 6.0 update](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/K-and-Vibe-Z-Series-Smartphones/Lenovo-K3-Note-Blocked-History-not-opening-after-Android-6-0/td-p/3297470)
- [How to Backup and Restore Call Logs on your Android Phone](https://theunlockr.com/2012/05/08/how-to-backup-and-restore-call-logs-on-your-android-phone/)

Summarizing the steps below from the above links:

1. Take back up of  contacts and call logs:

   - Used app [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) to create a backup of my call logs and message logs. (Got to know about the steps from my second link)
   - Created Contacts backup (Using *Export* option in Contacts app)
   - Created Blocked Contacts backup (using *Export black-n-white list* option in Contacts (Call / Messages Blocking section)
2. Go to *Settings → Apps → All apps →Contact Manager → Storage → Clear Data and Clear Cache*.

After this, I was able to see the Blocked History.
Though, I didn't need to import back my Call logs/ Contacts, but yes, I had to import Blocked Contacts. But, that's it and now I'm good.. :)

Hope this helps others who face this issue.. :)

Comment: Apologies.. Added the steps in the solution.

Comment: No need to apologise :). Upvoted answer for efforts. Also please delete your comment to keep thread clean